# Codenameone - Calendar createDay() Navigation

Tags: codenameone

I hand-coded my app using CN1 (based on CN1's standard form template). Mostly for using Calendar for appointment app (I have reason not to use Picker).

Here's my main Form class

```
public class celebriesta {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;

private Form home;

public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    // Pro only feature
    Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;

    }
        home = new Form("Home", BoxLayout.y());
        mainCalendar Calendar = new mainCalendar();
        home.addComponent(Calendar);
        Calendar.setUIID("Calendar");


    //Create Form1 and Form2 and set a Back Command to navigate back to the home Form        
    Form form1 = new Form("Form1");
    setBackCommand(form1);
    Form form2 = new Form("Form2");
    setBackCommand(form2);
    Form form3 = new Form("Form3");
    setBackCommand(form3);


    //Add navigation commands to the home Form

    NavigationCommand cmd1 = new NavigationCommand("Form1");
    cmd1.setNextForm(form1);
    home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd1);

    NavigationCommand cmd2 = new NavigationCommand("Form2");
    cmd2.setNextForm(form2);
    home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd2);

    NavigationCommand cmd3 = new NavigationCommand("Form3");
    cmd3.setNextForm(form3);
    Calendar.createDay().pressed();
    Calendar.createDay().released();
    Calendar.createDay().setCommand(cmd3);

    //Add Edit commands to the home Form context Menu
    Image im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MODE_EDIT, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
    Command edit = new Command("", im) {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Editing");
        }
    };
    home.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(edit);
    home.show();
}

protected void setBackCommand(Form f) {
    Command back = new Command("") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            home.showBack();
        }

    };
    Image img = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand"));
    back.setIcon(img);
    f.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar(back);
    f.getToolbar().setTitleCentered(true);
    f.setBackCommand(back);
}

public void stop() {
    current = getCurrentForm();
}

public void destroy() {
}}
```

I've override Calendar class accordingly

```
public class mainCalendar extends Calendar { @Override
    protected Button createDay(){ Button day = new Button();
    Image im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MODE_EDIT, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
    day.setIcon(im);

    return day;

   }     
    @Override
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {
    //Customize day values 
    dayButton.setText("" +day);
}}
```

The main Form manages to get to Form 1 & 2 (sidemenu). I know Form 3 does exist but not sure why it didn't managed to be 'reached' from createDay(). And I suspect it's something wrong somewhere around this code in main Form

```
Calendar.createDay().pressed();
Calendar.createDay().released();
Calendar.createDay().setCommand(cmd3);
```

Need advise and/or help.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at a [sample code here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/2214) that creates a custom calendar day component. You don't need the below code:

```
Calendar.createDay().pressed();
Calendar.createDay().released();
Calendar.createDay().setCommand(cmd3);
```

Calendar day pressing and releasing is handled through an `actionListener` which you can implement through overriding the `bindDayListener()` if you're using a custom day component or `addDayActionListener()` if you're using the default day button. An example will be:

```
Calendar.addDayActionListener(evt -> {
    //show your next form here
});
```

Unless you need a high-level customization, I don't see a point subclassing the Calendar class.

Comment: Thank you Diamond. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: TQ again Diamond. The code works. Mistakes on my code & also because I didn't update the CN1 libraries accordingly. Silly me...

Comment: @buzzin_hornets glad it worked...kindly upvote the answer

Comment: By the way, proper Java coding standard is starting variable names with lowercase, class names with uppercase and method/function names with lowercase. `mainCalendar` class should become `MainCalendar` and `Calendar` variable should be `calendar` or `cal`.

Comment: And constants with all UPPERCASE